# why does the app activity crash whenever i click on the listview to go to next activity

Tags: android

i cant seem to find where i have gone wrong in the code. cant proceed to MatchStats.class. in app logcat this line is where the error belongs                 String selectedMatch = listItems.get(position).toString();

below is the "main" activity

```
public class Matches extends AppCompatActivity {
private String selectedLeague;
private ListView listOfMatches;
private ArrayList<String> listCL = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_matches);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    Bundle b = in.getExtras();
    selectedLeague = b.getString("league");

    listOfMatches = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOfMatches);

    String[] CLMatches = new String[] { "Liverpool VS Real Madrid" };

    for(int i = 0; i < CLMatches.length; i++){
        listCL.add(CLMatches [i]);
    }

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listCL);
        listOfMatches.setAdapter(adapter);

    listOfMatches.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedMatch = listItems.get(position).toString();

            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MatchStats.class);

        }
    });
}
```

}

matchstats activity

```
public class MatchStats extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView choice;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_stats);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    Bundle b = in.getExtras();
    String selectedMatch = b.getString("match");

    choice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    choice.setText("You have selected the match " + selectedMatch);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`listItems` is empty, that's why you have a crash. You pass `listCL` to the adapter and then ask for items via `listItems` and of course it crashes.

Try changing your `OnItemClickListener` like this:

```
listOfMatches.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedMatch = listCL.get(position).toString();

        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MatchStats.class);

    }
});
```

Comment: doesnt crash now but still doesnt work. there is no logs either when it is click

Comment: Because you've just instantiated an `Intent` but you didn't call `startActivity(detailIntent)`. Then as @npk says in his answer pass a correct bundle through the intent or you will have a new `NullPointerException` in your new activity

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not passing any bundle to the intent. So `getExtras()` will return `null'.
You can pass the bundle like this:

```
Intent detailIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MatchStats.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("match", "value");
detailIntent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(detailIntent);
```

and access it just like you did.

**Another method:**

To pass the string, before calling `detailsIntent`, put the string into the intent.

```
Intent detailIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MatchStats.class);
detailIntent.putExtra("match", "some value");
startActivity(detailIntent);
```

And you can access this from `MatchStats` activity like this:

```
String selectedMatch = getIntent().getStringExtra("match"); // 'some value'
```